# How to pass an ng-repeat iterator to ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I have created this snippet in AngularJS that displays a pagination bar on my web page.  The object $scope.PagesOnBar contains an array of numbers like 1, 2, 3 which are appearing on the pagination bar.  The problem is in my ng-click attribute; the value {{x}} gets passed as a literal - the x is not replaced with 1, 2, 3.  How can I re-write this so that the numeric value is passed to the BarClick function?  I tried putting ng-repeat before ng-click and that didn't work either.  I also tried removing the curly braces - same result.

```js
    <ul class="PaginationBar">
    <li class="FloatLeft" ng-click="BarClick('<<');">&lt;&lt;</li>
    <li class="FloatLeft" ng-click="BarClick('<');">&lt;</li>
    <li class="FloatLeft" ng-click="BarClick('{{x}}');" ng-repeat="x in PagesOnBar">{{x}}</li>
    <li class="FloatLeft" ng-click="BarClick('>');">&gt;</li>
    <li class="FloatLeft" ng-click="BarClick('>>');">&gt;&gt;</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul class="PaginationBar">
    <li class="FloatLeft" ng-click="BarClick('<<');">&lt;&lt;</li>
    <li class="FloatLeft" ng-click="BarClick('<');">&lt;</li>
    <li class="FloatLeft" ng-repeat="x in PagesOnBar" ng-click="BarClick(x)">{{x}}</li>
    <li class="FloatLeft" ng-click="BarClick('>');">&gt;</li>
    <li class="FloatLeft" ng-click="BarClick('>>');">&gt;&gt;</li>
</ul>
```

Most `ng` directives don't need curly braces (`{{ }}`) to understand that you're referring to some sort of expression or variable.

Also, this may be just my preference, but I tend to declare the `ng-repeat` loop before I ever try to reference the iterated variable. It may be that Angular will still understand it, but at least for reading, it makes more sense to declare it first.

Comment: Harris - That worked.  So simple.  I forgot to remove the apostrophes.  I'll give you the answer when another 10 minutes passes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a literal, don't enclose x in `'`... Just write `x`